# Warning: copy(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;..file&quot;

Tags: css

here is a fiddle of a list Im working on.
Everything workd fin, but the display drops the right hand side borders.

I dont know why.   **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/rrp920yk/)**

ive tried to put a margin on the right of the container, but nothing...

```
.notifyContainer{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your problem right, but if you set `.content` and `.header` to `clear:both` the rows are displayed one below the other.

```
.header, .content {
    clear:both;
}
```

You also don't need `float:left` on them...

[Modified jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrp920yk/5/)